# Apache2 conf file redirecting requests for other enabled sites

Tags: apache2

I'm running apache2 on ubuntu 16.04. I've configured apache2 to run multiple sites. One of the sites has https setup and to help support this I've added the following rule to redirect http requests to use https:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName http://example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This has been too much of a blanket rule as it's redirecting other site's https requests to the domain above.

How can I re-configure the conf above to only redirect http requests for example.com and not the other sites on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first listed virtualhost for each host:port acts as the default, catching all unmatched ServerNames.  Make sure you don't define your special-case first.

See apachectl -S output for a summary of where your vhosts are loaded from and which one is the default.